# how to install a specific metacello group from command line in Pharo 9?

Tags: pharo, metacello

I'm running this line which used to work as expected in Pharo 8, but doesn't in Pharo 9/10:

```
    ./pharo bootstrap.image metacello install tonel://./src BaselineOfPowerlang --groups=base
```

Instead of installing the base group, in Pharo 9 it installs everything (the dev group), so I guess the cli API changed.
The baseline is in the [Powerlang repo](https://github.com/powerlang/powerlang/blob/master/bootstrap/src/BaselineOfPowerlang/BaselineOfPowerlang.class.st).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is failing (it shouldn't), but you can workaround the problem by executing:

```
./pharo bootstrap.image eval --save "
    Metacello new
        repository: 'tonel://./src';
        baseline: 'Powerlang';
        load: 'base'
"
```

I hope it helps!